# How to run java application by clicking .exe not jar file in any computer without installing jdk nor jre

Tags: java

I have done my project every thing is fine but my problem is how can i run the program in any other computers so that others  can use it without instal jdk nor jre.

Comment: Without using JRE? No, it's not possible (at-least not at the level of having JRE)

Comment: Are you asking how to run a Java application without having Java installed?

Comment: i want to know if possible to run without java instaled @ claymore1977

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't**. You need at least the JRE installed on the client machine. The best you can do is create an EXE program that has the JRE embeded and when run it first time you install the JRE then you run your java program.

Comment: thanks for advice am now searching for that approach, it seem to be nice approach, though might be tough coz am still young in java, i have recently graduated this course

Comment: For that I will recommend you to use [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) it is very easy to learn and it is for this type of purpose (installation) but you can customize it to check if the program (on this case JRE) is installed and if it is you just call your java programa (by line command).

Answer (score 0):

**It is not possible.**

For any jar file you must have installed **JRE** (at least).
If you mean that you can use [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) for example, it uses already installed JRE. Another example is [Excelsior](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/) which runs lightweight JRE also.